# Duplicate folders and change a value in a file from that folder

Tags: bash, shell

I have a folder called main. I want to duplicate this folder along with all its files 300 times and rename each new folder as example0, example1, example2, example3 .... example300.

There are many files in the folder. I want to find the file config.ini, look for this line "amount = 0" each time, increment that 0 by 1 each time a new folder is created.

So example0 folder's config file amount value will be 0, example1 folder's config file amount value will be 1 and so on.

Can I get some help with this please. I would have just created the folders manually but 300 is a bit much. Looking for a simpler way. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for i in {0..300} # for loop to iterate from 0 to 300
do
cp -R main "example$i"
sed -i "s/amount = 0/amount = $i/" "example$i/config.ini"
done
```

should do it.

---

**What is happening here?**

1. The `for-loop` opens a counter `i` for you whose value sequentially go on from 0 to 300
2. `cp -R main "example$i"` recursively copy main to example0, example1 and so on.
3. sed command takes care substituting the string *amount = 0* to *amount = counter* and the `-i` option makes the edit inplace.

Comment: The Bash style loop may be a bit more readable `for i in {1..300}`.

Comment: @Kenavoz : Thankyou but coming from `c` background i feel other way. Editing anyways :) Actually it is `for i in {0..300}` to fit the requirement

Comment: @sjsam Truly appreciate the simplified explanation as to whats going on in the code. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this and pass max value of folders you want to multiply as a first argument of this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(seq 1 $1) ; do
    cp -r main example$i
    sed -i "s/amount = 0/amount = $i/g" "example$i/config.ini"
done
```

Explanation:

`cp` does recursive copy of `main` to directory `exampleX` where `X` is a number from range from `1` to value passed as first argument of the script.

`sed` does a replacement of every `amount = 0` with `amount = X` (X is equal to a number). If only one `amount = 0` exist in config.ini you can skip the `g` at the end of sed script

To replace exactly 300 times replace first line with

```
for i in $(seq 1 300) ; do
```

Comment: Not sure you need to use the `g` flag with `sed` and it is suggested to double quote `example$i/config.ini`

Comment: True. `g` is for global replacement. I'll edit. thanks